# Easy method to solve multiplication of many numbers followed by division

Tags: math, long-integer, multiplication, division, multiple-value

Please help for easy method to solve longish multiplications and division equation.
Example like (667 x 6 x  74) / (384 x 384)
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Are you asking how to parse and evaluate arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to break it down and multiply divisions.
also it might be even better if you would sort the numbers in each group and pair the biggest of each group.

For example:

instead of `(667 * 6 * 74)/(384 * 384)`
you can do `667/384 * 74/384 * 6`.

instead of `(5 * 234 * 98 * 3433) / (2 * 34 * 7 * 333)`
you can do `3433/333 * 234/34 * 98/7 * 5/2`.

Comment: Thank you TOHB for suggetion. This will help

Comment: Your example would fail in languages like C or C++ where `/` stands for integer division, since in that case `(667 * 6 * 74)/(384 * 384) == 2` but `667/384 * 74/384 * 6 == 0`.

Comment: this question wasn't language specific, it was more of a concept.. in many languages you can do some more sophisticated things.